# Electric charge and the distance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, charge

The strength of an electric field is: $E = 200\ \mathrm{N/C}$

The potential (of the test charge) is: $V = 600\ \mathrm{V}$

$\epsilon_r=1$

I need to calculate the distance between this point and the charge, the size of the charge.
I think that the distance between this point and the charge is $E/V\implies E=V/m$, so it's $3$. To calculate the size of the charge, I used:

$$ E=\frac{kQ}{r^2},$$
So,

$$Q=\frac{E r^2}{k},$$

but I'm not sure what $k$ and $\epsilon_r$ are.

Comment: Did you try to look it up in a textbook?!

Comment: yes, I tried...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$k=\frac1{4\pi\epsilon_0}=98.9\times 10^9 \:\mathrm{N m^2 C^{-2}}$

This is [Coulomb's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_constant), part of Coulomb's law: $$\vec F=\frac{kq_1q_2\hat{r}}{r^2}=\frac{q_1q_2\hat{r}}{4\pi\epsilon_0r^2}$$

($\epsilon_0$ is the [permittivity of free space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_permittivity), and is another constant)

In a dielectric medium, you replace $\epsilon_0$ with $\epsilon_r\epsilon_0$(the permittivity in that medium) in this equation, since the induced charges decrease the force. In case of a vacuum (and to an approximation, air), $\epsilon_r=1$